# Disable Validation in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have this model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [RegularExpression(@"[^/\\|""<>:?'\*\[\]=%$+,;~#&{}]*", ErrorMessage = @"Illegal characters: / \ | "" ' < > [ ] { } : ; , ~ ? = + * % $ #")]
    public string Reference{ get; set; }
}
```

Because of business requirements the list of invalid characters needs to get expanded. The problem is that there are already `Reference`'s in the database containing the extra illegal characters. Now when the view is rendered, it breaks (FormatException triggered by the RegexAttribute) on the `@Html.TextBoxFor()`-line.

```
using (Html.FormGroupFor(x => x.DocReference))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Reference)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Reference)
}
```

The strange thing is, I ALWAYS get an exception. Even when the data doens't have any illegal characters.

- Why am I getting this error?
- How can I get rid of this validation check on GET-action but still keep the validation when the user posts the form?

**Edit:**
When the errors pops op. I close it and set the execution to a line before `@Html.TextBoxFor`. When the compilers gives the TextBox a second try, there is no exception.

Comment: _How can I get rid of this validation check on GET-action but still keep the validation when the user posts the form?_ Perhaps remove the attribute, check the value in the post action method (e.g. `Regex.IsMatch()`) and if it fails, add a ModelStateError and return the view?

Comment: I thought at this but then I would lose my client-side validation.

Comment: Should the asterisk in the regex be escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the error wasn't because of the wrong regular expression or witchcraft. When writing curly braces in a literal string, you must escape them. Below is the fixed regular expression + the fixed error message.

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^/\\""\|<>:\?'\*\[\]\=%\$\+,;~#&\{\}]*", 
 ErrorMessage = @"Illegal characters: / \ | "" ' < > [ ] {{ }} : ; , ~ ? = + * % $ #")]
```